# how to know if an embedded ember application is ready

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have a simple static html page with an ember application implemented via a `<script>` tag.
On this page I also have a loading animation in a `div` with the class loader that I want to hide once the ember application is started or ready.

In my html code I have to place the following div:

```
<div id="tool-wrapper" data-tool-locale="en"></div>
```

The Ember App then places it's content into this `div`. I already tried to place my code into this div, hoping that the code would be replaced, but unfortunately that did not work because the ember app appends it's code into this `div`.

Since I don't know Ember.js, and the code of the application is minimized, I hope that someone can tell me an default event from Ember.js or something like that I can wait for and then use JS to hide my `div` with the loader animation.

Comment: you can just put the loader in the root element. ember will take over the DOM and remove it.

Comment: @Lux I tried this already, but the loader just append's its code -.- (i updated my problem description)

Comment: I think we need to know more about what you mean by “started or ready”. The Ember router automatically produces loading substates, so if you make an `application-loading` template, that’s what’ll be rendered until the application route is ready.

Comment: @BuckDoyle I mean the moment, the ember app appends their code into the div#tool-wrapper. At this time, I have to remove my div.loader.

Comment: What about something like [ember-load](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-load)?

Comment: Hey @BuckDoyle thanks for helping me further, but we're not allowed to alter the ember code, because it's an external provided script with regular updates. That was the reason why i thought there must be an event which i can listen for.

Comment: hmm if you can’t change the Ember application at all, I can’t think of a way to detect loading externally, I don’t think there’s an event propagated outside Ember, which tends to be self-contained